# BIOS Update current procedure(s)

Tags: 18.04, bios

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Tower PC  which was originally loaded with Windows Vista Operating System.  I have tried  several times to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from the current 16.04. Download was successful: however, the  system would not start up.

Next burned a startup disc from Ubuntu website and tried to boot with that – download and burn were successful, but again system would not start up.

My guess is that I need to update the original Dell Vista  BIOS (A01) to current (0360-A07), but do not know how to do this from Ubuntu OS.

Any help with this , or other advise would be much appreciated.
THANKS

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln171755/updating-the-dell-bios-in-linux-and-ubuntu-environments?lang=en

Comment: I wish hp had same useful link!

Comment: HP ... do to... Here you go @GeorgeUdosen https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c00234553

Comment: Why do you think you need to update the BIOS ? it could simply be that you have an old 32bit processor that does not run the latest 18.04 x64 bits ubuntu.